# invalid opcode: opcode 0x5f not defined

Tags: solidity, erc-20, evm, opcode, binance-smart-chain

I'm new to Solidity and it's my first try to write a smart contract using Openzeppelin, Pancakeswap and BEP20 libraries basically to make a BEP-20 token.

When i try to deploy the smart contract, i get the following error : "invalid opcode: opcode 0x5f not defined" and in my case i know that the OpCode must begin with 0x608....
I found that others had the same issue, but i still can't found the errors in my code.

It would be great if someone can help me.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is because solidity 0.8.20 introduces the PUSH0(0x5f) opcode which is only supported on ETH mainnet and not on any other chains. That's why other chains can't find the PUSH0(0x5f) opcode and throw this error.

Consider using 0.8.19 for other chains.

This should solve your problem.

If you want to learn more about PUSH0 opcode you can check this small article which explains it pretty well. https://www.zaryabs.com/push0-opcode/

Comment: Oh, you're right. It's working. Thank you :D

Answer (score 6):

[`0x5f` is the `PUSH0` opcode](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3855) which [**Solidity 0.8.20**](https://blog.soliditylang.org/2023/05/10/solidity-0.8.20-release-announcement/) started generating:

> This compiler switches the default target EVM version to Shanghai,
> which means that the generated bytecode will include PUSH0 opcodes. Be
> sure to select the appropriate EVM version in case you intend to
> deploy on a chain other than mainnet like L2 chains that may not yet
> support PUSH0, otherwise, deployment of your contracts will fail.

For deploying to other chains (that do not support 0x5f), you can select the EVM version as follows:
`solc --evm-version <VERSION> contract.sol`

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.20/using-the-compiler.html#setting-the-evm-version-to-target lists other EVM versions like `paris`, `london`, `berlin`.

Alternatively, as suggested by @Zartaj, use an older compiler version.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of going back to an older version of Solidity compiler, in hardhat to prevent use of `PUSH0` you can try setting `evmVersion` to a previous version (e.g. `paris`, which is the one before `shanghai`) whilst still using the latest compiler version (0.8.21 currently):

```json
solidity: {
    compilers: [
      {
        version: `0.8.21`,
        settings: {
          optimizer: {
            enabled: true,
            runs: 15000
          },
          evmVersion: `paris`
        }
      },
    ],
  },
```

Polygon announced last week that they’ve just implemented `PUSH0` on their zkEVM blockchain. I’ve tested the testnet and it works. zkEVM mainnet will work from 2023-09-10: [Polygon zkEVM: Dragon Fruit Upgrade (with New Opcode) Coming to Mainnet Beta](https://polygon.technology/blog/polygon-zkevm-dragon-fruit-upgrade-with-new-opcode-coming-to-mainnet-beta)

I also tested 140 blockchains today and only found these ones (16%) that support `PUSH0` currently:

- auroraTestnet
- edgeware
- edgewareTestnet
- gnosis
- chiado
- goerli
- mainnet
- moonbaseAlpha
- moonbeam
- moonriver
- polygonZkEvmTestnet
- pulsechain
- pulsechainV4
- sapphire
- sapphireTestnet
- scrollSepolia
- sepolia
- syscoin
- syscoinTestnet
- taikoTestnetSepolia

Hopefully the many other blockchains will follow, as developers want to be able to use the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error. This is how I fixed it.
To fix this error make sure solidity version is less that 0.8.20. I used 0.8.19 both in .sol file and package.json
For specific version in  package.json  use command

```
npm install solc@0.8.19
```

After that I re-generate .abi and .bin file using below commands.

if you using npm:

```
npx solcjs --bin --abi --include-path node_modules/ --base-path . FileName.sol
```

if you using yarn:

```
yarn solcjs --bin --abi --include-path node_modules/ --base-path . FileName.sol
```