# Invalid opcode error in ganache 2.7.1

Tags: contract-deployment, dapps, web3.py, ganache

I have created a smart contract and deployed it using web3.py by connecting to the ganache 2.7.0 version and deployed the smart contract in it but suddenly there was a update in ganache which I did and suddenly got i[image]nvalid opcode error but my code was running fine in the older version

Comment: Which solc version are you using? Did you try updating ganache? It could be related to this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/150281/invalid-opcode-opcode-0x5f-not-defined.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, I was using ethers.js and solc with JavaScript. Issue was fixed by changing my solc version to "0.8.7-fixed"