# Error deploying my contract

Tags: binance-smart-chain

Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"invalid opcode: opcode 0x5f not defined","id":2405066928997542}

Comment: Duplicate? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/150281/invalid-opcode-opcode-0x5f-not-defined
See if this solves your issue.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/150281/invalid-opcode-opcode-0x5f-not-defined , you can come here to check the answer, i confirmed this worked

Answer (score 1):

`0x5F` is EVM opcode `PUSH0` that was introduced in the `shanghai` update to Ethereum around 5 months ago. Most other EVM-based blockchains still haven't implemented it.

I tested 140 blockchains today and only found these ones (16%) that support `PUSH0` currently:

- auroraTestnet
- edgeware
- edgewareTestnet
- gnosis
- chiado
- goerli
- mainnet
- moonbaseAlpha
- moonbeam
- moonriver
- polygonZkEvmTestnet
- pulsechain
- pulsechainV4
- sapphire
- sapphireTestnet
- scrollSepolia
- sepolia
- syscoin
- syscoinTestnet
- taikoTestnetSepolia

Polygon announced last week that they’ve just implemented `PUSH0` on their zkEVM blockchain. I’ve tested the testnet and it works. zkEVM mainnet will work from 2023-09-10: [Polygon zkEVM: Dragon Fruit Upgrade (with New Opcode) Coming to Mainnet Beta](https://polygon.technology/blog/polygon-zkevm-dragon-fruit-upgrade-with-new-opcode-coming-to-mainnet-beta)

Hopefully the many other blockchains will follow, as developers want to be able to use the latest version.

In the meantime, in hardhat to prevent use of `PUSH0`, you can try setting `evmVersion` to a previous version (e.g. `paris`, which is the one before `shanghai`) whilst still using the latest compiler version (0.8.21 currently):

```json
solidity: {
    compilers: [
      {
        version: `0.8.21`,
        settings: {
          optimizer: {
            enabled: true,
            runs: 15000
          },
          evmVersion: `paris`
        }
      },
    ],
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is about the version of solidity.
There is a significant update in the latest solidity version 0.8.20 about PUSH0 opcode. please check the following link:
https://medium.com/coinmonks/push0-opcode-a-significant-update-in-the-latest-solidity-version-0-8-20-ea028668028a