# I am trying to replicate a deployed contract but it doesn't work for me. I want to learn to please tell me what I am doing wrong. Goerli lets me do it

Tags: solidity, remix

contract : https://codeshare.io/BA1yqK

The error : Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"execution reverted","id":7152909631495616}

- Checked optimisations
- Copy pasted same code
- Works on goerli but not on mainnet or sepolia

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have directly copied the contract from Etherscan, which I believe is a flattened file. You need to take out the relevant contract from this and only deploy that one, not the whole flattened file.

Also please share the contract address from where you copied so that I can confirm the above statement.

Another issue might be the version, please try once with 0.8.19. [ref](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/150286/104252)