# Web3.py exception contract logic error; execution reverted: VM exception

Tags: solidity, remix, blockchain, web3.py, ganache

I would like to contract the transactions to solidity compiler and got the following error;
**raise ContractLogicError(f"execution reverted: {message}", data=data)
web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode**

The details about the code and error log is provided in image file.

I would be thankful for your suggestions to solve this issue.[image: web3.py code to transact to smart contract]
[image: solidity code]
[image: error log file]

Comment: This might help https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/150286/104252

Comment: i am still getting the error.