# I'm getting this Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit

Tags: ganache, vscode

***MY CODE:***

---

```
const ethers = require("ethers");
const fs = require("fs-extra");

async function main() {
  // HTTP://172.17.32.1:7545
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
    "HTTP://172.17.32.1:7545"
  );
  // need Private key and provider
  const Wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
    "0x4fdf1fc96f1c08aa3e80bbbed50d2fd3d5b8a0197bf9107770b773e2b89bfc46",
    provider
  );
  const abi = fs.readFileSync("SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi", "utf8");
  const binary = fs.readFileSync("SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin", "utf8");
  const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, Wallet);
  console.log("Deploying, please wait...");
  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy();
  console.log(contract);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit();
  });
```

---

***IDK what this is but I'm using Ganache and getting UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT***

---

***THIS MY ERROR IS:***

```
saad@DESKTOP-PREQOSC:~/BC/ether-simple-storage$ node deploy.js
Deploying, please wait...
<ref *1> Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (error={"reason":"processing response error","code":"SERVER_ERROR","body":"{\"id\":49,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"error\":{\"message\":\"VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode\",\"stack\":\"RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode\\n    at exactimate (C:\\\\Program Files\\\\WindowsApps\\\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\\\app\\\\resources\\\\static\\\\node\\\\node_modules\\\\ganache\\\\dist\\\\node\\\\1.js:2:182136)\",\"code\":-32000,\"name\":\"RuntimeError\",\"data\":{\"hash\":null,\"programCounter\":24,\"result\":\"0x\",\"reason\":null,\"message\":\"invalid opcode\"}}}","error":{"code":-32000,"data":{"hash":null,"programCounter":24,"result":"0x","reason":null,"message":"invalid opcode"}},"requestBody":"{\"method\":\"eth_estimateGas\",\"params\":[{\"type\":\"0x2\",\"maxFeePerGas\":\"0xd09dc300\",\"maxPriorityFeePerGas\":\"0x59682f00\",\"from\":\"0x42eeee4f7d882ca1d73a980d771a513f05f96a89\",\"data\":\"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\"}],\"id\":49,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}","requestMethod":"POST","url":"HTTP://172.17.32.1:7545"}, tx={"data":"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","from":"0x42EEEE4F7d882Ca1d73a980D771A513f05F96A89","type":2,"maxFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0xd09dc300"},"maxPriorityFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x59682f00"},"nonce":{},"gasLimit":{},"chainId":{}}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=abstract-signer/5.7.0)
    at Logger.makeError (/home/saad/BC/ether-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:238:21)
    at Logger.throwError (/home/saad/BC/ether-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:247:20)
    at /home/saad/BC/ether-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/abstract-signer/lib/index.js:365:47
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 6) {
  reason: 'cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit',
  code: 'UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT',
  error: Error: processing response error (body="{\"id\":49,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"error\":{\"message\":\"VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode\",\"stack\":\"RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode\\n    at exactimate (C:\\\\Program Files\\\\WindowsApps\\\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\\\app\\\\resources\\\\static\\\\node\\\\node_modules\\\\ganache\\\\dist\\\\node\\\\1.js:2:182136)\",\"code\":-32000,\"name\":\"RuntimeError\",\"data\":{\"hash\":null,\"programCounter\":24,\"result\":\"0x\",\"reason\":null,\"message\":\"invalid opcode\"}}}", error={"code":-32000,"data":{"hash":null,"programCounter":24,"result":"0x","reason":null,"message":"invalid opcode"}}, requestBody="{\"method\":\"eth_estimateGas\",\"params\":[{\"type\":\"0x2\",\"maxFeePerGas\":\"0xd09dc300\",\"maxPriorityFeePerGas\":\"0x59682f00\",\"from\":\"0x42eeee4f7d882ca1d73a980d771a513f05f96a89\",\"data\":\"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\"}],\"id\":49,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}", requestMethod="POST", url="HTTP://172.17.32.1:7545", code=SERVER_ERROR, version=web/5.7.1)
      at Logger.makeError (/home/saad/BC/ether-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:238:21)
      at Logger.throwError (/home/saad/BC/ether-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:247:20)
      at /home/saad/BC/ether-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:313:32
      at step (/home/saad/BC/ether-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:33:23)
      at Object.next (/home/saad/BC/ether-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:14:53)
      at fulfilled (/home/saad/BC/ether-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:5:58)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
    reason: 'processing response error',
    code: 'SERVER_ERROR',
    body: '{"id":49,"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"message":"VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode","stack":"RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode\\n    at exactimate (C:\\\\Program Files\\\\WindowsApps\\\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\\\app\\\\resources\\\\static\\\\node\\\\node_modules\\\\ganache\\\\dist\\\\node\\\\1.js:2:182136)","code":-32000,"name":"RuntimeError","data":{"hash":null,"programCounter":24,"result":"0x","reason":null,"message":"invalid opcode"}}}',
    error: Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
        at getResult (/home/saad/BC/ether-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:191:21)
        at processJsonFunc (/home/saad/BC/ether-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:356:22)
        at /home/saad/BC/ether-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:288:46
        at step (/home/saad/BC/ether-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:33:23)
        at Object.next (/home/saad/BC/ether-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:14:53)
        at fulfilled (/home/saad/BC/ether-simple-storage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:5:58)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
      code: -32000,
      data: [Object]
    },
    requestBody: '{"method":"eth_estimateGas","params":[{"type":"0x2","maxFeePerGas":"0xd09dc300","maxPriorityFeePerGas":"0x59682f00","from":"0x42eeee4f7d882ca1d73a980d771a513f05f96a89","data":"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"}],"id":49,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}',
    requestMethod: 'POST',
    url: 'HTTP://172.17.32.1:7545'
  },
  tx: {
    data: '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',
    from: '0x42EEEE4F7d882Ca1d73a980D771A513f05F96A89',
    type: 2,
    maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0xd09dc300', _isBigNumber: true },
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x59682f00', _isBigNumber: true },
    nonce: Promise { 0 },
    gasLimit: Promise { <rejected> [Circular *1] },
    chainId: Promise { 1337 }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a "invalid opcode" error. If your contract uses solidity 0.8.20 (or greater), try changing it to a lower version and recompiling:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.19;
```

See this post for more details: [invalid opcode: opcode 0x5f not defined](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/150281/invalid-opcode-opcode-0x5f-not-defined)