Ganache-UI connection with Remix IDE
I connected Ganache-UI with Remix and able to view all the accounts and balances, but upon deploying a basic contract, I get such message:
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending? 

processing response error (body="{\"id\":62,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"error\":{\"message\":\"VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode\",\"stack\":\"RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode\\n    at exactimate (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/1.js:2:182136)\",\"code\":-32000,\"name\":\"RuntimeError\",\"data\":{\"hash\":null,\"programCounter\":21,\"result\":\"0x\",\"reason\":null,\"message\":\"invalid opcode\"}}}", error={"code":-32000,"data":{"hash":null,"programCounter":21,"result":"0x","reason":null,"message":"invalid opcode"}}, requestBody="{\"method\":\"eth_estimateGas\",\"params\":[{\"from\":\"0x9d786Cb9310Fc1AB16d141754130566ea0D8eB1f\",\"data\":\"0x6080604052348015600e575f5ffd5b50603e80601a5f395ff3fe60806040525f5ffdfea2646970667358221220b183f23534140944928c1f0f898c62c18e61756498a8f2d782c6549e70f56ceb64736f6c634300081c0033\",\"value\":\"0x0\",\"type\":\"0x2\",\"maxFeePerGas\":\"0x4f790d55\"},\"latest\"],\"id\":62,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}", requestMethod="POST", url="http://127.0.0.1:7545", code=SERVER_ERROR, version=web/5.7.1)
The EVM version used by the selected environment is not compatible with the compiler EVM version.

Earlier (2-3 years back) all used to work fine but it seems it cannot happen, I checked full configuration, I am not able to determine it.
Any leads?

Does this answer your question? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/157005/75850

Hello, My question is different, I am referring more on remix IDE (browser).

if you're using ganache it's still the same. It doesn't support the new opcode

Got it. Thank you!
