# Missing Revert Data (Hardhat/Ganache)

Tags: solidity, javascript, hardhat, ganache, revert

```js
 shortMessage: 'missing revert data',
  info: {
    error: {
      message: 'VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode',
      stack: 'RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode\n' +
        '    at exactimate (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/1.js:2:182136)',
      code: -32000,
      name: 'RuntimeError',
      data: [Object]
    }
```

Following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyMwXuJrbJQ) at **7.06.00** timestamp, I coded this after setting up ganache network. But the `missing revert data` error is showing. What can I do?

Raised the same as a [discussion](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-js/discussions/6516) on the corresponding repo of the tutorial.

Comment: Does this answer your question - https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/150281/invalid-opcode-opcode-0x5f-not-defined/150286#150286

Comment: Yes I found my answer, the answer is using a fixed version of Solc-js as some latests opcodes does support only in Ethereum Mainnet, here comes the stable Solc@0.8.14-fixed version which did my job done. Thank You for enlighten me with this nice blog.

Comment: That's great. Happy to help.