Truffle deployment Failed " hit an invalid opcode while deploying."
This is a token maker code, so its failing to deploy with the following reason:
> *** Deployment Failed ***

"TokenMaker" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:
   * Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
   * Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
   * Adding reason strings to your assert statements.


Exiting: Review successful transactions manually by checking the transaction hashes above on Etherscan.


Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"TokenMaker" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:
   * Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
   * Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
   * Adding reason strings to your assert statements.

This is the code below
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Token is ERC20 {
    address private _owner;
    uint8 private _decimals;
    uint256 private _totalSupply;
    
    constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_, address _tOwner, uint8 decimals_, uint256 _tSupply) ERC20(name_, symbol_) {
        _owner = _tOwner;
        _decimals = decimals_;
        _totalSupply = _tSupply * (10 ** uint256(decimals()));
        _mint(_owner, _totalSupply);
    }

    function owner() public view returns(address){
        return _owner;
    }
    function decimals() public view override  returns(uint8){
        return _decimals;
    }

    function totalSupply() public view override returns(uint256){
        return _totalSupply;
    }

}
contract TokenMaker{
    uint256 public baseFee = 0.0005 ether;
    mapping(address => address) private _myToken;
    address public owner;
    bool locked;

    constructor(){
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function create(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        address _owner,
        uint8 _decimals,
        uint256 _totalSupply
        ) public payable{
            require(msg.value == baseFee, "Insufficient Fee");
            _myToken[msg.sender] = address(new Token(
               _name,
               _symbol,
               _owner,
               _decimals,
               _totalSupply
            ));
        }

    function withdraw() public {
       require(!locked, "Locked");
       require(owner == msg.sender, "Not owner");
       require(address(this).balance > 0, "Insufficient contract balance");
       locked = true;
       payable(owner).transfer(address(this).balance);
       locked = false;
    }

    function myToken() public view returns(address){
        return _myToken[msg.sender];
    }
}

this is the deployment script:
const TokenMaker = artifacts.require('TokenMaker');
const Token = artifacts.require('Token');

module.exports = function(deployer){
   
    deployer.deploy(TokenMaker);
}


Try looking at the solutions here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/150281/invalid-opcode-opcode-0x5f-not-defined
